# Looping through excel sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am looping through Excel files in a folder to consolidate all data in one new spreadsheet in a new file.

I have three Excel files open at the same time:

- The 1st one is the main file in which I am writing the code.
- The 2nd one is the file from which I am copying.
- The 3rd one is the new file in which I am trying to consolidate
  the data.

The problem is when I open one of the files to be copied from (2nd file) and copy/paste the data to the new 3rd file, I am unable to close the 2nd file.

So this is the issue.
I tried a lot but couldn’t get to the end of it.

Comment: Help us to help you; **post your current code**.

Comment: `Workbooks.Open()` returns a reference to the opened file - use that to keep track of each workbook

Comment: [This example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54119778/issues-with-find-and-replace-all-with-multiple-files-in-same-directory-excel-v/54120090#54120090) shows something similar: Each workbook is opened and referred to with **ActiveWorkbook**, something is done to its worksheets and then it is closed with **.Close True** where **True** means it is saved. Since you will only get data out of the workbooks, you will use **.Close False** to not save any changes. But without your code, there is little to be done to help you. An edit button is below your post. Use it to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by the comments, without code it is difficult to help you.

However, hopefully this can help you out and give you some ideas.

This is code that I use to prompt a file picker dialog box to select files. This will prompt for 1 file and set it as `wb_file1` and the active worksheet as `ws_file1`. You can modify the worksheet to whatever you need it to be. However, if the file names are always the same, you could create a loop to go through the files.

Just make sure to set the workbooks and worksheets so you can reference them and make changes easily.

```
Dim wb_file1 As Workbook
Dim ws_file1 As Worksheet
Dim fileName As String

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = "Select the file"
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Custom Excel Files", "*.xlsx, *xls, *csv"
        .Show
        fileName = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
    End With
    If InStr(fileName, ".xlsx") = 0 Then
    Exit Sub
    End If
    Workbooks.Open fileName
    'Set the Workforce Review raw workbook
    Set wb_file1 = ActiveWorkbook
    'Set the worksheet
    Set ws_file1 = wb_imd.ActiveSheet
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, you did this , really helped a lot.